# Не волен/неволен

Tags: грамматика

"В цене купец волен, а в весе  не волен" — верно ли написано слово «не волен»?

Answer (score 2):

Да, в этом предложении слово "не волен" написано верно, так как здесь явное отрицание признака "волен". Волен? Нет.  Кроме того, можно вставить слова, усиливающие отрицание: ***отнюдь*** не волен.

***ПАС Лопатина***:
...при отсутствии в контексте слов, помогающих распознать отрицание или утверждение и, следовательно, отличить частицу не от приставки не-, пишущий должен проверить, какие слова — ***усиливающие отрицание*** или подчеркивающие утверждение — возможны по смыслу в данном контексте.
***При возможности подстановки слов, выражающих противопоставление или усиливающих отрицание*** (вовсе, отнюдь и др.), ***не пишется раздельно***, напр.: Путь туда (отнюдь) не далёкий; Погода была (нисколько) не жаркая; Он (далеко) не спокоен; Они (ничуть) не виновны; Живут они (вовсе) не богато; Признаться в своей ошибке (вовсе) не унизительно; Уехал, но (отнюдь) не надолго; Может быть, (вовсе) и не плохо, что он туда не попал; Разобраться в этих правилах (ничуть) не легко.

Answer (score 0):

Возможность подстановки слов, выражающих противопоставление или усиливающих отрицание есть всегда. А как же быть с школьным правилом: если можно слово заменить синонимом без НЕ, то НЕ пишется слитно? При этом, конечно, не должно быть слов, выражающих противопоставление или усиливающих отрицание, и противопоставления с союзом А.

Comment: Сомнение Ваше понятно: правописание НЕ с разными частями речи - тема не из лёгких. Вариативность действительно существует, особенно когда речь идёт о НЕ с прилагательными и наречиями на -о. Но выход один -  вчитаться в предложение, почувствовать его, понять, не рассматривать его как мёртвую схему, к которой следует применить правило. Домик был невысокий, ладненький, аккуратненький. Явно "невысокий" = "маленький". Правило здесь работает. Брат её не высокий(=отрицание высокого роста); брат её невысокий (утверждение того, что он маленький).